# How can I check my python 3 code works with any version?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want universal compatibility with any python 3 version for my python 3 code. How can I ensure my code will work with any version and will work the same? Is there a checker that can tell me if my code will break in certain versions or coding guidelines I should follow to ensure my code will work for all versions?

Comment: You could run your tests against multiple versions with e.g. [`tox`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking code for compatibility with Python 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815079/checking-code-for-compatibility-with-python-2-and-3)

Comment: This depends. f.e. the order of keys inside Dictionaries was changed from "implementation detail" to "insert order" somewhere between 3.6 and 3.8 depending on which implementation you have. If your code somewhere _depends_ on the ordering of the keys of a dict, it may have changed behaviour.. doubt you can catch those things automagically.

Comment: *Any* Python 3 version is probably not necessary. I very much doubt anyone going to the trouble of switching from Python 2 to Python 3 would stick with 3.0, for instance. I recall 3.3 being the first "real" version of Python 3 (in that it restored `u'...'` literals to aid in Python 2 migration), and I very much doubt there is any serious use of versions earlier than Python 3.5.

Comment: The preservation of dictionary insert order was a CPython implementation detail in Python 3.7, with it becoming a language guarantee in Python 3.8. You could use an `OrderedDict` in any version if that's a requirement, though there is still a subtle different between an `OrderedDict` and an ordered `dict`: the former uses the ordering when comparing for equality, while the latter does not.